# pip install azure-functions in azure pipeline fails with pip authenticate task

Tags: python, azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-artifacts

I am building a CI/CD azure pipeline to build and publish an azure function from a DevOps repo to Azure. The function in question uses a custom SDK stored as a Python package Artifact in an organisation scoped feed.

If I use a pip authenticate task to be able to access the SDK, the task passes but the pipeline then crashes when installing the requirements.txt. Strangely, before we get to the SDK, there is an error installing the azure-functions package. If I remove the SDK requirement and the pip authenticate task this error does not occur however. So something about the authenticate task means the agent cannot access azure-functions.

[image: error message]

Additionally, if I swap the order of 'azure-functions' and 'CustomSDK' in the requierments.txt, the agent is still unable to install the SDK artifact so something must be wrong with the authentication task:

```
steps:
- task: PipAuthenticate@1
  displayName: 'Pip Authenticate'
  inputs:
    artifactFeeds: <organisation-scoped-feed>
    pythonDownloadServiceConnections: <service-connection-to-SDK-URL>
```

Why can I not download these packages?

Answer (score 1):

This was due to confusion around the extra index url. In order to access both PyPI and the artifact feed, the following settings need to be set:

```
- task: PipAuthenticate@1
  displayName: 'Pip Authenticate'
  inputs:
    pythonDownloadServiceConnections: <service-connection-to-SDK-Feed>
    onlyAddExtraIndex: true
```

This way pip will consult PyPI first, and then the artifact feed.

Answer (score 0):

- Try running the function while the `_init_.py` file is active on the screen.
- If you're just trying out the Quickstart, you shouldn't need to change anything in the `function.json file`. When you start debugging, make sure you're looking at the `_init_.py` file.
- When you run the trigger, make sure you're on the `_init_ .py` file. Otherwise, VS Code will try to run the current active window's file.